# John Conway's Game of Life in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, game-of-life, sfml

I have created Game of Life in C++ SFML. The code works just fine. However since I am not used to working with C++, I implemented a lot of stuff the way I would in python (for example I have not used pointers). So I would appreciate any feedback (even if it is really nitpicky) on my project. My goal with this project is the build good fundamentals before I work on bigger projects.

Main:

```
#include "Grid.hpp"

void handle_mouse(Grid &grid, sf::RenderWindow &window )
{
    sf::Vector2i position = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
    int x = position.x;
    int y = position.y;

    int i = int(y/TILE_SIZE);
    int j = int(x/TILE_SIZE);
    grid.change_tile(i,j);
}


Grid grid;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "SFML works!");
    grid.reset();
    bool draw_mode = true; 

    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            
            if (draw_mode)
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
                {
                    handle_mouse(grid, window);
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space)
                {
                    draw_mode = false;
                    window.setFramerateLimit(4);
                }
            }
            if (not draw_mode and event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::LControl)
            {
                grid.reset();
                draw_mode = true;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        grid.draw(window);
        window.display();
        if (not draw_mode) {grid.update();}
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Grid.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "settings.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Grid{

public:

   void reset();
   void update();
   void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);
   int check_nearby_cells(int i, int j);
   void change_tile(int i, int j){Grid::array[i][j] = !Grid::array[i][j];}
   
   bool array[NUM_VERTICAL_TILES][NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES];
};
```

Grid.cpp

```
#include "Grid.hpp"
#include <iostream>

sf::RectangleShape get_rectangle(int i, int j, bool filled);

void Grid::reset()
{
   for (int i=0; i<NUM_VERTICAL_TILES; i++)
   {
      for (int j=0; j<NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES; j++)
      {
         Grid::array[i][j] = false;
      }
   }
}



void Grid::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
   for (int i=0; i<NUM_VERTICAL_TILES; i++)
      {
         for (int j=0; j<NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES; j++)
         {    
            bool filled = Grid::array[i][j];
            sf::RectangleShape rectangle = get_rectangle(i, j, filled);
            window.draw(rectangle);   
         }
      }
}

void Grid::update()
{
   bool new_array[NUM_VERTICAL_TILES][NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES];
   for (int i=0; i<NUM_VERTICAL_TILES; i++)
   {
      for (int j=0; j<NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES; j++)
      {
         int num_adjacent_cells = check_nearby_cells(i, j);
         
         if (Grid::array[i][j])
         {
            if (num_adjacent_cells <2 or num_adjacent_cells>3) {new_array[i][j] = false;}
            else {new_array[i][j] = true;}
         }
         else
         {
            if (num_adjacent_cells == 3) {new_array[i][j] = true;}
            else {new_array[i][j] = false;}
         }
      }
   }
   for (int i=0; i<NUM_VERTICAL_TILES; i++)
   {
      for (int j=0; j<NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES; j++)
      {
         Grid::array[i][j] = new_array[i][j];
      }
   }

}

bool is_valid(int i, int j)
{
   return (i>=0 and j>=0 and i < NUM_VERTICAL_TILES and j < NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES);
}

int Grid::check_nearby_cells(int i, int j)
{
   int count = 0;
    for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
            // Skip the (i, j) tile itself
            if (x == 0 and y == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_valid(i + x, j + y) and Grid::array[i + x][j + y]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}


sf::RectangleShape get_rectangle(int i, int j, bool filled)
{
   sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
   rectangle.setPosition(j*TILE_SIZE, i*TILE_SIZE);
   rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE));
   if (filled)
   {
      rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
   }else{
      rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
   }
   rectangle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
   rectangle.setOutlineThickness(1);
   return rectangle;
}
```

settings.hpp

```
#pragma once

constexpr int WIDTH = 1200;
constexpr int HEIGHT = 800;
constexpr int TILE_SIZE = 50;
constexpr int NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES = WIDTH/TILE_SIZE;
constexpr int NUM_VERTICAL_TILES = HEIGHT/TILE_SIZE;
```

Comment: In `update()`, testing 3 nbrs and then assigning true or false is tedious. Simply assign the `... == 3` boolean expression and be done with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## General Observations

Not too bad if this is your very first C++ program.

You need to become aware of the Standard Template Library which provides data structures such as [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The way the arrays are currently implemented is a lot more like the C Programming language than C++. Naming the array `array` may also have caused some problems.

Generally header files in C++ use the `.h` notation, there are libraries where there are `.hpp` but these are generally header files that contain executable code and not just header information. I would suggest changing `settings.hpp` to `settings.h`.

Separate the game logic from the input and output. The Grid class should only contain information about the game and not about input or output. You may not have encountered design patterns yet, but there are several design patterns that deal with separating the I/O from the logic of the program. Some of these are [Model View Controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and [Model View View Model (MVVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

In modern C++ we avoid pointers as much as possible.

## Avoid Global Variables

It is very difficult to read, write, debug and maintain programs that use global variables. Global variables can be modified by any function within the program and therefore require each function to be examined before making changes in the code. In C and C++ global variables impact the namespace and they can cause linking errors if they are defined in multiple files. The [answers in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) provide a fuller explanation.

Not only is `grid` a global variable, all of the constants defined in `settings.hpp` are global variables.

It might be better in `settings.hpp` if each constant was declared as `static` so that it is local to the file including `settings.hpp`

```
static constexpr int WIDTH = 1200;
static constexpr int HEIGHT = 800;
static constexpr int TILE_SIZE = 50;
static constexpr int NUM_HORIZONTAL_TILES = WIDTH / TILE_SIZE;
static constexpr int NUM_VERTICAL_TILES = HEIGHT / TILE_SIZE;
```

Currently if `settings.hpp` is included by multiple files there may be link time errors about the constants being declared in multiple files.

## Magic Numbers

The frame rates in the `main()` are magic numbers, there are a number of symbolic constants already defined in settings.hpp, why aren't the frame rates defined there as well?

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the feedback and I would like to clarify a few things. "Separate the game logic from the input and output" what do you mean by this. Does this mean that the grid should not a draw function and that the draw function should be somewhere else in the program (or do you mean something entirely else). And also if we want to avoid pointers in the first place why do people ever use them?  It almost feels like "avoid pointers" would be one of the easiest rules to follow.

Comment: @Doruk I've added some references about "Separate the game logic from the I/O.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Why do we avoid pointers in C++? I thought the whole point of C++ was to have low level access to memory?

Comment: @SomeGuy Before the Template Library when we had to write our own container classes pointers were needed a lot more. The advent of std::vector and lists really made it easier not to use pointers. There are still need for pointers if you are trying to address memory locations, but that is limited to special needs these days. Pointers was one of the things I had to unlearn, you might want to look at the answers to my early question here on code review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw What would be good place to learn where I actually need pointers and where I can avoid them?

Comment: @Doruk I'm writing the game of life as well, in WinUI/Windows App SDK/C++. I'd recommend watching the C++ Series of videos from "The Cherno" on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb. This is also recommend https://www.learncpp.com/ And I'd also recommend https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHTh1InhhwT5o3GwbFYy3sR7HDNRA353e Feel free to take a look at my code here, which I'm sure also could be better. https://github.com/mgradwohl/ModernLife